# C++: Make an array out of the elements of a two dimensional array that meet certain requirements

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am new to multi-dimensional arrays, the question I am struggling with right now is the following: I have a "maxn" number of days, and the highest and lowest temperature recorded for these days and I have to do certain things with this data. One of these things is to determine the days when the temperature has been both below and above 0 (i.e.: the lowest recorded temp was below and the highest was above). The program has to output the number of days when such a thing occurred as well as the index of these days.

However, no matter which loop I use and how, I mess it up and either I get something absolutely irrelevant or an infinite loop. Here is what I have so far:

```
void abovebelow (int n, float days[maxn][2]{

int counter=0;
float a[maxn];

for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
     for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
          if ((days[i][0]<0 && days[i][1]>0) || (days[i][1]<0 && days[i][0]>0)){
           counter++;
           i=a[j];
      cout<<counter<<" "<<a[j]<<" ";
   }
    }

}
```

Comment: There a syntax error in function declaration..

Comment: Note that the `maxn` in the function declaration doesn't do anything.  Your function is the same as if it was declared `void abovebelow(int n, float days[][2])` or as `void abovebelow(int n, float (*days)[2])`.  Arrays are never passed by value in C++; when an array is passed to a function, it is implicitly converted to a pointer to its initial element.  When you see an array type function parameter, it's really the same as a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with simple for-loop. Why use two nested loops for that?

And plus, the if-condition could be modified to:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if (days[i][0]*days[i][1]<0) {
        counter++;
        cout<<"Day "<<i+1<<endl;
    }
}
cout<<"Counter: "<<counter<<endl;
```

PS:

1.I hope its a typo in the code you have pasted. There's a syntax error in the function declaration.

2.In standard C++, there's no VLA (you are unknowingly using your compiler specific extra). Unless `maxn` is a `const` (thanks, James), You would need to:

```
float *a = new fload[n];

//do all the stuffs here

delete[] a;
```

Comment: Because I don't only need the counter, I also need the index of the days when this happened and one for-loop only prints out the first occurrence of this not all of them. I will edit my question to make it more clear!

Comment: `maxn` may be a constant, in which case the declarations are well-formed.

Comment: Oh, yes! I am used to seeing consts in all uppercase :)

Comment: I couldn't edit my comment but I just realized that I made a mistake with my input file, which is why I thought I only got the first occurrence, I have now tried the simple loop you suggested again and it does work, I am sorry and thank you!

Comment: And yes, maxn is a constant, I should make it all uppercase, though!